# Filter using model field and reverse look up

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models

Business:

```
credit_officer (FK -> User)
```

Loan:

```
business (FK -> Business)
disbursed()
active()
```

I want to get business who belong to a given credit_officer and have business.loan_set.active().count() == 1

This is how I was getting business for the given credit_officer but I don't know how to add the other condition business.loan_set.active().count() == 1

```
cro_businesses = (
    Business.objects.filter(credit_officer=credit_officer_id)
    .values("id", "name", "credit_officer__id")
    .order_by("_created_at")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the model and other details like what are the fields and how they are connected with business and credit_officer any foreign key or anything.